# Problema al mostrar imagen desde URL Xamarin Forms

Tags: imagen, xamarin.forms

estoy programando una App en xamarin que pretende mostrar el menú de un restaurante, dicho menú ya existe de manera digital en línea, por lo que las imágenes simplemente deben tomarse de la carpeta online, algo tan simple como esto:

```
<Image Source="(URL de la imagen)"></Image>
```

El problema es que la URL tiene el siguiente formato:

http://31.207.89.53:8095/Contenido/img/Menu/Tortas.jpg

Al parecer, el hecho de haber agregado a la URL un puerto, provoca problemas para que xamarin muestra la imagen. Lo lógico seria simplemente cambiar la dirección del menú a una sin un puerto, pero esta parte del proyecto no puede cambiarse por dos razones:

1.- Lo administra un tercero.

2.- El restaurante ya tiene impresos sus QR con esta dirección.

Entonces, ¿alguien tiene idea de como hacer que xamarin muestra la imagen?

Comment: No hay ningún problema en la url y que tenga puerto en la dirección, pero me queda la duda como la estas queriendo pasar

Comment: Lleno un Generic List de un objeto llamado Producto, específicamente el campo de la imagen es un "string Fotografia {get; set;}, la URL ya se proporciona desde la base de datos y en el XAML lo llamo así: <Image Source="{Binding Fotografia}"></Image>

Comment: agregalo en el codigo de la pregunta, seguramente te esta faltando implementar INotifyPropertyChanged y no se refresca la vista cuando llegas las url